# Highlight link when scroll the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and this code is intended for a simple program that updates navigation based on scroll position to indicate which link is currently active in the viewport when scrolling the page.

The problem is when I scroll down the page it throws this error:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'add')`

Any solution will be appreciated.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <style>
    #navigation {
    position: fixed;
}
#sections {
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
}
.section {
    height: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
#section5 {
    height: 1000px;
}
.active {
    background: red;
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Section 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Section 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="sections">
    <section id="section1" class="section">
        I'm section 1
    </section >
    <section  id="section2" class="section">
        I'm section 2
    </section >
    <section id="section3" class="section">
        I'm section 3
    </section >
    <section id="section4" class="section">
        I'm section 4
    </section >
    <section id="section5" class="section">
        I'm section 5
    </section >
</div>
  
<script>
var navigationLink = document.querySelectorAll('#navigation > ul > li > a');
let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section[id]');
var sectionIdTonavigationLink = {};
for (var i = sections.length -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var id = sections[i].id;
sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = '#navigation > ul > li > a [href=\\#' + id + ']'.classList.add('active') ;
}
function highlightNavigation() {
    var scrollPosition = window.pageYOffset ;

    sections.forEach(function(items) {
        var currentSection = items;
        var sectionTop = currentSection.offsetTop;
            if (scrollPosition >= sectionTop) {
            var id = currentSection.getAttribute('id');
          var $navigationLink = sectionIdTonavigationLink[id];
            
            // if the link is not active
             $('#navigation > ul > li > a').removeClass('active');
            $('#navigation > ul > li > a[href=#' + id + ']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
}
</script>
</script>
```

Comment: `sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = '#navigation > ul > li > a [href=\\#' + id + ']'.classList.add('active') ;` looks wrong. You probably want something closer to `sectionIdTonavigationLink[id] = $('#navigation > ul > li > a[href="#' + id + '"]').addClass('active');`

Comment: @kmoser how do i remover link ID after click on it? example #section3

Comment: Your links don't have IDs, they have hrefs (e.g. `#section3`). Why would you want to remove those hrefs?

Comment: when i click on them they appear on url bar something like this .. blah/blah/#section

Comment: That's how anchor links are intended to work. What were you expecting?

Comment: this #section2 should not appear on url bar when i click its coresponding navlink @kmoser

Comment: @kmoser the solution isn't working as it was expected it highlight all anchor link at once even before scrolling